# How can I find OpenJDK's JRE package?

Tags: java

I need to install only the JRE package of OpenJDK. I am not able to find it anywhere. Is there a package available?

I tried searching the web as well. I found no package like that.

Comment: `openjdk-[version]-jre`

Comment: What operation system are you using? As @BackSlash pointed out the package manager of your linux distribution should have it with the provided naming scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [official](https://openjdk.java.net/install/) page, JDK and JRE were different before Java 9, but from Java 9-10-11, it is not different anymore.
For Java-8 and before there were separate commands

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

More info at [here](https://medium.com/azulsystems/using-jlink-to-build-java-runtimes-for-non-modular-applications-9568c5e70ef4)